# How can I select a row from a SparseTensor in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, embedding

Say, if I have two `SparseTensor`s as following:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 2, 0, 0]]
```

and

```
[[1.0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1.0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0.3, 0.7, 0, 0]]
```

and I want to extract the first two rows out of them. I need both indices and values of non-zeros entries as `SparseTensor`s so that I can pass the result to `tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse`. How can I do this?

My application is:
I want to use word embeddings, which is quite straight forward in TensorFlow. But now I want to use sparse embeddings, i.e.: for common words, they have their own embeddings. For rare words, their embeddings are a sparse linear combination of embeddings of common words.
So I need two cookbooks to indicate how sparse embeddings are composed. In the aforementioned example, the cookbook says: For the first word, it's embedding consists of its own embedding with weight 1.0. Things are similar for the second word. For the last word, it says: the embedding of this word is a linear combination of the embeddings of the first two words, and the corresponding weights are 0.3 and 0.7 respectively.
I need to extract a row, then feed the indices and weights to `tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse` to obtain the final embeddings. How can I do that in TensorFlow?

Or I need to work around it, i.e.: preprocess my data and deal with the cookbook out of TensorFlow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I checked in with one of the engineers here who knows more about this area, and here's what he passed on:

I am not sure if we have an efficient implementation of the this, but here is a not-so-optimal implementation using dynamic_partition and gather ops.

```
def sparse_slice(indices, values, needed_row_ids):
   num_rows = tf.shape(indices)[0]
   partitions = tf.cast(tf.equal(indices[:,0], needed_row_ids), tf.int32)
   rows_to_gather = tf.dynamic_partition(tf.range(num_rows), partitions, 2)[1]
   slice_indices = tf.gather(indices, rows_to_gather)
   slice_values = tf.gather(values, rows_to_gather)
   return slice_indices, slice_values

with tf.Session().as_default():
  indices = tf.constant([[0,0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1]])
  values = tf.constant([1.0, 1.0, 0.3, 0.7], dtype=tf.float32)
  needed_row_ids = tf.constant([1])
  slice_indices, slice_values = sparse_slice(indices, values, needed_row_ids)
  print(slice_indices.eval(), slice_values.eval())
```

Update:

The engineer sent on an example to help with multiple rows too, thanks for pointing that out!

```
def sparse_slice(indices, values, needed_row_ids):
  needed_row_ids = tf.reshape(needed_row_ids, [1, -1])
  num_rows = tf.shape(indices)[0]
  partitions = tf.cast(tf.reduce_any(tf.equal(tf.reshape(indices[:,0], [-1, 1]), needed_row_ids), 1), tf.int32)
  rows_to_gather = tf.dynamic_partition(tf.range(num_rows), partitions, 2)[1]
  slice_indices = tf.gather(indices, rows_to_gather)
  slice_values = tf.gather(values, rows_to_gather)
  return slice_indices, slice_values

with tf.Session().as_default():
  indices = tf.constant([[0,0], [1, 0], [2, 0], [2, 1]])
  values = tf.constant([1.0, 1.0, 0.3, 0.7], dtype=tf.float32)
  needed_row_ids = tf.constant([0, 2])
```

Comment: Oh, I see. It uses a clever combination of dynamic_partition and gather. The idea is, DO NOT form a SparseTensor. Instead, just perform `dynamic_partition` and `gather` on dense `indices` and `values` array.

Comment: This helps a lot! By the way, this code seems to only work for a single row. how can I extract multiple rows (even with duplication)? Say, if I want to extract the 1st, 3rd and 3rd row? Which means, in an input sentence, there may exists some words appear multiple times. I know I can run `sparse_slice` several times, and use `tf.concat` to concatenate them up, but is there a better way?

Comment: Finally I got it. I can perform partition on dense `indices` and `values` similarly. I'll post a solution tomorrow, which heavily uses `tf.gather`.

Answer (score 1):

Let `sp` be the name of your 2d SparseTensor. You can first create an indicator tensor for the rows of your SparseTensor that you want to extract, namely

```
mask = tf.concat([tf.constant([True, True]), tf.fill([sp.dense_shape[0] - 2],
    False)], axis=0)
```

Next use tf.gather to propagate this to the sparse indices:

```
mask_sp = tf.gather(mask, sp.indices[:, 0])
```

Finally,

```
values = tf.boolean_mask(sp.values, mask_sp)
indices = tf.boolean_mask(sp.indices, mask_sp)
dense_shape = [sp.dense_shape[0] - 2, sp.dense_shape[1]]
output_sp = tf.SparseTensor(indices=indices, values=values, dense_shape=dense_shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it behave more like this:

This version will keep the order and frequency of the indices in selected_indices and, therefore, makes it possible to e.g. select the same row multiple times:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

def sparse_gather(indices, values, selected_indices, axis=0):
    """
    indices: [[idx_ax0, idx_ax1, idx_ax2, ..., idx_axk], ... []]
    values:  [ value1,                                 , ..., valuen]
    """
    mask = tf.equal(indices[:, axis][tf.newaxis, :], selected_indices[:, tf.newaxis])
    to_select = tf.where(mask)[:, 1]
    return tf.gather(indices, to_select, axis=0), tf.gather(values, to_select, axis=0)


indices = tf.constant([[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 0], [7, 0]])
values = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 7.0], dtype=tf.float32)
needed_row_ids = tf.constant([7, 3, 2, 2, 3, 7])
slice_indices, slice_values = sparse_gather(indices, values, needed_row_ids)
print(slice_indices, slice_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer by "Pete Warden" which only worked for small data. Given sparsetensor A with m nonzero elements, we would like to take out n rows. The tf.equal would take m*n space, which is not acceptable in my task.

My suggestion is to use Scipy.sparse instead of tensorflow.
In details:

1. take out all data from tf, indices & data, and form a Scipy.sparse. use coo
2. If u need to take out rows, use csr formate. if u need to take out cols, use csc
3. A[:,m]
4. transform to coo
5. transform to tf